# Fill last semi-empty column

Tags: two-column

In the past I have written a series of columns titled **Glisterings** which were published in *TUGboat* which is a two-column format. I am now trying to collect them all together in a book following the same two-column format, with each published column being presented as a `\chapter`. This has led, in some cases, for the last page of a chapter consisting of: one (short) column or one full column followed by a short (or empty) second column. I would like to be able to automatically fill the second column with some graphic if it is too short (for some definition of short). I know that I could do it manually for each chapter but I'm a lazy GOM (Grumpy Old Man). Is there an automatic way of doing this? Here is an example of a manual method.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4] % makes a short second column
\vfill
\centering
 PUT TALL GRAPHIC HERE
\vfill
\mbox{}
\end{document}
```